# How can I unescape a UTF-8 string in c++

Tags: c++, linux, utf-8

It's a little different from many cases I have searched.

I receive a string such as the following :

```
std::string str = "\\u8f93\\u5165\\u7684";
```

How can I parse the escape sequences to construct an actual UTF-8 string ?

Comment: What do you mean by decode?

Comment: You can loop through each character, if it's a backslash followed by `u`, read the next 4 characters, parse them to an integer using `std::strtol()`, and append that as a character to another appropriately-typed string, e.g. `std::basic_string<uint32_t>`.

Comment: That's two questions: How to unescape to UTF-16, and how to convert that to UTF-8. The former is some mediocre bitwiggling (as TPC pointed out), for the latter (and handling of Unicode in general) I'd suggest [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Comment: @DevSolar while ICU is a good general advice, UTF to UTF conversions are part of C++11

Comment: @Cubbi: Standard C++ is still rather poorly equipped when it comes to handle the finer points of character sets, that's why I recommend to not bother. Sooner or later you will run afoul of things like `toupper( 'ß' )`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple parse-and-convert job, for example could be done this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
int main()
{
    std::string str = "\\u8f93\\u5165\\u7684";
    std::u16string u16;
    qi::parse(str.begin(), str.end(), *("\\u" >> qi::hex), u16);
    std::string u8 = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t>().to_bytes(u16);
    std::cout << "utf 8 string " << u8 << " consiting of " << u8.size() << " bytes\n";
}
```

Live at coliru http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62efb680a3d27a60

Answer (score -2):

**Note: this answer was posted before a clarifying edit was added to the question.**

---

Just pass it to string like "\u8f93\u5165\u7684"

Or:

```
#include <codecvt>
std::string(u8"\u8f93\u5165\u7684")
```

Comment: I'm afraid this does not answer the question. From what I've understood, OP has a string containing literally "\u8f93\u5165\u7684", and wants to parse the escape sequences to construct an actual UTF-8 string.

Comment: @Quentin 's understanding is right. I have received a defined string like what I mentioned above. The question is how to get an actual UTF-8 string from that.

Comment: @ericxluo the word you're looking for is "unescape".